# if conditional is not working in Velocity

Tags: c#, velocity

I have an issue with an *if* conditional in Velocity. I’m trying to do a validation of the properties `NombreDestinatario` and `NombreRemitente` that come from the next JSON object.

```
{
    "CartaPorte":
    {
        "Shipment": "AB1234561",
        "Agenda" : " ",
        "NombreRemitente": "Josue",
        "RFCRemitente": "afgd4567",
        "Ubicaciones":
        {
            "Ubicacion":
            [
                {
                    "Origen":
                    {
                       "RFCRemitente": "ABC123456789",
                       "PrimerOrigen": "true",
                       "NombreRemitente": "CEDIS 1 S.A. de C.V",
                       "NombreComercialOrigen": "Bodega 1"
                    },
                    "Domicilio":
                    {
                        "Calle": "Calle 1",
                        "Estado": "CHH",
                        "Pais": "MEX",
                        "CodigoPostal": "32434"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Destino":
                    {
                        "RFCDestinatario": "GHI123456789",
                        "UltimoDestino": "true",
                        "NombreDestinatario": "CEDIS 2 S.A. de C.V",
                        "NombreComercialDestino": "Bodega 2"
                    },
                    "Domicilio":
                    {
                        "Calle": "Calle 1",
                        "Colonia": "Tabacalera",
                        "Localidad":"001",
                        "Municipio": "Cuautitlan",
                        "Estado": "CHH",
                        "Pais": "MEX",
                        "CodigoPostal": "32434"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Mercancias":
        {
            "NumTotalMercancias": "4",
            "Mercancia":
            [
                {
                    "BienesTransp": "10101508",
                    "Descripcion": "Cabras",
                    "Cantidad": "10",
                    "ClaveUnidad": "X2C",
                    "PesoEnKg": "100",
                    "NombreComercialOrigen": "Bodega 1",
                    "NombreComercialDestino": "Bodega 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to construct a table with velocity, but it seems that my *foreach* loop is being executed twice and I don’t know why. Here is the table that is being generated and additionally the code in velocity. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Generated table]

[image: Code in Velocity]

Comment: I see JSON and a couple of links, but no code and nothing about velocity. If you want us to see your code, please include it in your question

Comment: I could find a solution for the problem above but another came to the scene. ¿How can I check for if an object is null in velocity?

Comment: If you have another question, please create a new post.